# rails and "gem cancan". certain attributes in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

this idea ... user on his page can see all of his data, while other users only specific attribute (example: email).

I use "gem cancan" Where necessary to prescribe the "select"? rails ought to show certain field.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution I can think of off the top of my head would be to to divide up the `user#show` page into partials.  Then, you could run `can? :read, :attribute` for each individual partial, and setup abilities for each `:read, :attribute` either for all users or for just `@user == user` in ability.rb.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense, and I'll try to pseudo-code an example